# Does Crystal report open handle to default printer even if no printing is done

Tags: crystal-reports

Does Crystal report open handle to the default printer when a report is run? even if the result report is never printed?

Thanks in advance,
Su

Answer (score 0):

Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and check for yourself, Su.

Comment: I did use Process Explorer to figured out that there are handles to the Printer in use. I was looking to see if this is normal behavior by Crystal report, or could this be because that some reports are not designed properly?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this is just normal behaviour - try it with a simple report and see.  It could be that it's getting its hands on the printer information for page formatting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports page layout is designed to mimic what would come out on paper, so it queries your printer to find out its capabilities. So, I'm pretty sure the answer is yes. It certainly complains if it can't query your default printer.